# How to migrate from JCAPS to WSO2 ESB

Tags: java, wso2, esb, jcaps, wso2-esb

We are using a [JavaCAPS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Caps) (JCAPS 5.X and 6.X) and want to migrate to [WSO2 ESB](http://wso2.com/products/enterprise-service-bus/). Now the question is how we can migrate with as much automatic migration as possible.

TThe JCDs can be migrated to a custom mediator class that is being by a WSO2 proxy or sequence. But our main issue is the migration of the different OTD(Object Type Definitions) like DatabaseStockedProcedure, WebService, CustomTextFile, ...

**Are there any tools or howto guides to convert the JCAPS components to WSO2 compatible components (or standard Java implementations like JAXB or similar)?**

(Please no recommendations for other ESB)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There was a post on Linkedin regarding [this](http://www.linkedin.com/groupItem?view=&gid=876687&type=member&item=204641575&qid=419cfe4f-5efe-47fc-8ffe-0f63c0d386b8&trk=group_most_recent_rich-0-b-cmr&goback=.gmr_876687.gde_876687_member_200182440.gmr_876687.gde_876687_member_200925637.gmr_876687.gde_876687_member_202228007.gmr_876687) . You may need to have a linkedin profile to see the discussion.

Answer (score 0):

There are some new additional slides about the implementation of the [Migration from JCAPS to WSO2](http://de.slideshare.net/avintis/avintis-jcaps-migration).