# Migrate from JCAPS to WSO2 ESB

Tags: jcaps, wso2-esb

We have an application that uses JCAPS.

Since JCAPS is no longer available, we are trying to migrate the application from JCAPS to WSO2 ESB.

Could anybody provide any documentation or guide to start the migration work.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has already been asked and answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14355598/how-to-migrate-from-jcaps-to-wso2-esb).

Pls refer the [slide deck](http://www.slideshare.net/avintis/avintis-jcaps-migration) as well.

Comment: Thank you Rajeev. The slide is more useful.

Comment: The linkedin post is not available. Could you please share the post, if it is availble.

Comment: I searched for it and couldn't find it either. Better to contact the person who pointed to the article in that answer.